# Theoretical efficiency of a gas burner

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Is it theoretically possible to transfer the temperature from a burning gas let say acetylene or propane to a liquid or gasous substance moving through a system of  pipes like water or air in the way that final temperatures of outgoing burned gas and heated substance in pipes that leaves their thermodynamic contact area are nearly equal?

Comment: This is a continuous flow reactor operating at steady state, right?

Answer (score 0):

To a good approximation, yes. The device used to make such measurements is called a *bomb calorimeter* and the general topic of measuring heat release in chemical reactions is called *calorimetry*.